# Android - Remove data from SDCard

Tags: java, android

My application use the SDCard to store data (about 100 Mb of stuff). I would like to delete these file when the application is deleted through the application manager and offer a way to clear the data from there (like the Google Apps does). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

> **Accessing files on external storage**
>
> If you're using API Level 8 or greater, use **getExternalFilesDir()** to open a File that    represents the external storage directory where you should save your files. ...  **If the user uninstalls your application, this directory and all its contents will be deleted.**

From my understanding this will create a file on the sd card which has a scope (like a directory of your applications package namespace) and the phone will delete the directory when you uninstall the app. I assume this is how Google apps achieves this function.

Comment: Yes this works, your data should be in SDCard/Android/data/your.app.namespase/ folder. In this case all data with namespace folder will be removed automatically.